Way to convert a latex file to pdf only with python? (without having to locally install anything)
I am building a mathematical software with PyQt, and I would like to provide the users with a result in a file written in LaTex and also the compiled version of it in PDF. However, I can't find a way to do so. All solutions I've seen require me to install a compiler locally.
I cannot expect the users to install a compiler in their computers once they have executable version of the software. That is why I am looking for a solution that does not requires my system to have it.
This question is not about displaying mathematical typesetting in Qt, but about generating a document report in LaTex and also a easy way to visualize it in PDF.

You will have to pack a latex compiler with your program.

No, there's no way. You will need to install a python library, which defeats the rule of not installing anything.

Is your question only about typesetting equations or about typesetting complete documents in LaTeX? If equations only, then maybe you could follow an approach similar to the one described here. In short, it uses MathJax to render equations in a QWebEngineView. I guess this would likewise be possible with KaTeX. No need for a local LaTeX installation, but the necessary JavaScript libs will need to be loaded from their corresponding URLs. The QWebEngineView provides printToPdf() for PDF output.

The question is about complete documents! We process some equations, and provide a report afterwards. As our users uses our software in their research, we figure would be nice to generate a document in a way they could just copy and paste in their articles - and also easily (and conveniently) visualize as a .PDF.

Thanks for the clarification. In this case, I am afraid, I agree with the other commenters: If you want to typeset in LaTeX, you need to ship a LaTeX environment yourself (if you don't want your users to install it separately).

LaTeX  uses a complex typesetting engine. That's why it's used - a professional grade typesetting engine. Something needs to do that typesetting.  One way is to "just" reimplement that engine in python yourself. Maybe you only need a subset of LaTeX. Maybe you can convert the LaTeX syntax into something more simple like markdown and render that to PDF.
For math typesetting, katex as mentioned in a comment might be an option for you.
Maybe your use case allows you to make it a client server software architecture and do the compiling on a server. LaTeX.Online has a docker container to create the API
Others mentioned the traditional way, just package the dependency.

I cannot expect the users to install a compiler

That is why you should install it with the rest of your program.
MiKTeX allows for a silent installation.
TeX live has similar options
